# Can I rely on sizeof(uint32_t) == 4?

Tags: c++

I know I can rely on `sizeof(char) == 1`, but what about `sizeof(uint32_t)`  and `sizeof(uint8_t)`?
Shouldn't it be 32bit (8bit) in size guessing from the name?
Thanks!

Comment: It would be very inconsistent if `sizeof()` would return bits instead of bytes in only those cases.

Comment: Obviously, as long as `CHAR_BIT == 8`, you can. Nowadays it is not easy to find an architecture where that is not so.

Comment: `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes, `uint32_t` specifies the width in bits, so basically, what are the number of bits in a byte on the target platform? See `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy I've heard that there are a lot of embedded processors where `CHAR_BIT == 32`.  (I haven't worked on embedded processors for the last 30 years, so I don't know from experience.  But one of the last I worked on didn't have byte addressing, and the usual implementation would have had `CHAR_BIT == 16`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, I suppose that's true -- but that's quite a segregated niche in programming. Most developers are dealing with mainstream architectures which it seems are finally settled at `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy It's clearly a specific domain.  I suspect that it concerns a larger number of programmers than you think, however; there are a lot more embedded processors than desktops or mainframes.

Comment: I've heard of some exotic platforms where 1 byte == 7 bits, but are there any that have 16-bit bytes?

Answer (score 19):

The fixed-sized types will always be exactly that size. If you're on some weird platform that doesn't have integer types of that size then they will be undefined.

Note that it doesn't necessarily follow that `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`, if `CHAR_BIT != 8`; again this only occurs on weird platforms.

Answer (score 15):

Absolutely not, at least with regards to `sizeof(uint32_t)`.
`sizeof` returns the number of bytes, not the number of bits,
and if a byte is 16 bits on the platform, `sizeof(uint32_t)`
will be 2, not 4; if a byte is 32 bits (and such platforms
actually exist), `sizeof(uint32_t)` will be 1 (and `uint32_t`
could be a typedef to `unsigned char`).

Of course, in such cases, `uint8_t` won't be defined.

Comment: But does size_of return the number of *bytes* or the number of *chars*? Are they any cases when CHAR_BIT != 8?

Comment: @user2864740 `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be equal to 1.

Comment: @user2864740, In C/C++ object model, `char` is byte by definition.

Comment: `sizeof` always returns the number of bytes. `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: And there are systems floating around today where `CHAR_BIT == 32` (and probably some with `CHAR_BIT == 16`).  And it's not been too long ago that there was a system with `CHAR_BIT == 9` being produced (but of course, that one wouldn't have `uint32_t` defined, since there weren't any 32 bit types on it).

Answer (score 2):

NO, it is entirely dependent on your compiler and architecture(*ie, it will give different results where you dont have integer types*). If you get `CHAR_BIT == 8` then yes you can rely on that. So if you are on 64bit architecture will be aligned to 64 bit boundaries same as on 32 bit architecture everything is aligned to 4 bytes.

So If the data size is critical (eg a set of bit flags) always use the fixed-size types.

Comment: I don't get this. Wouldn't this imply that `malloc(sizeof(unit32_t) * x)` requests "twice the space" on a 64 vs 32 arch?

Comment: @user2864740:- The alignment requirement of uint32_t must be less than or equal to sizeof(uint32_t). Because of the requirement that there be no padding in uintN_t types, sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT == 32. Anything else is non-conforming to C99.

Comment: So is it dependent (as in answer) or guaranteed (as in comment) for uint32_t? :>

Comment: No it means that the first byte of the allocated memory starts at an address that is dividable by 16 (16 byte alignment on 64-bit windows platforms)

Comment: @user2864740:- I would say that if CHAR_BIT == 8 then it is guaranteed else it is dependent

Comment: @R.T. Ah, that bit about CHAR_BIT makes more sense. Thanks.